# how to convert array in php

Tags: php, arrays

Hi i got this array  from my database.

```
 array (size=4)
      0 => 
        array (size=1)
          0 => 
            array (size=1)
              'email_1' => string 'denise@aaa.com' (length=18)
      1 => 
        array (size=1)
          0 => 
            array (size=1)
              'email_1' => string 'denise@aaa.com' (length=18)
```

And i need to do get like this

```
array (size=4)
  0 => 
    array (size=1)
        email_1' => string 'denise@aaa.com' (length=18)
  1 => 
    array (size=1)
        'email_1' => string 'denise@aaa.com' (length=18)
```

I tried with array_merge and all. But no idea how to archive this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do it like below:-

```
$final_array = array();

foreach($original_array as $key=>$val){
 $final_array[$key][] = $val[0]['email_1'];
}
print_r($final_array);
```

Output:-https://eval.in/848213

Answer (score 1):

In php it is possible to do like this

```
  foreach ($yourArray as $arr){
      $result[] =  $arr[0];
   }
```

You can get also your desired output like this:

```
 $result = array_map('array_collapse',$yourArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

For this just assign like this to its first element.

```
foreach($yourArray as $array){
  $array = $array[0];
}
```

Comment: This wouldn't work. it would only allow access to the first email address.